# Exercise solutions for "3264 and all that"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Please excuse, that this is not exactly a math question, but I do not know of a better forum to ask publicly and I do not want to contact the authors of the abovementioned book before having asked the public:

In the book "3264 and all that" by Eisenbud and Harris, in Chapter 0, page 8, it is said that Francesco Cavazzini prepared solutions for the exercises in the book, which appear on a web site associated to the book.

Unfortunately I was not able to locate this website or another place in the web, where these solutions are given. Does anyone know, where they can be found?

Comment: not clear he put the solutions online http://www.math.harvard.edu/~franc/pdfs/CV_cavazzani.pdf  although the book authors expected that

Comment: @WillJagy: The link appears to be broken.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm, did you end up contacting the authors and what did they say? Perhaps you could post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @JW I talked with prof Harris recently and he said the solutions were not completed due to Cavazzani getting a job in finance and at least temporarily leaving academia.

Comment: @TejasRao, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the solutions on David Eisenbud's [website](https://eisenbud.github.io/), solutions [here](https://eisenbud.github.io/3264%20solutions.pdf).